# Is there a way to move files without closing python?

Tags: python, directory, move

I have a program that makes calculus, converts different data and plots it while saving it in different directories. So far, so good BUT. Whenever I want to move the files generated to another folder without closing Python it doesn't let me only with one of them, telling me that a program still has it open and I can't move it. The weird part is that I can take out all the plots generated so it's the folder itself that can't be moved. I don't know what to do because other folders are generated and treated the same way and don't give me problems. Any idea?

TL;DR: Can't move a empty folder while Python is still open

```
path_data_anaconv = path_data + r'TheProblem/' 
if not os.path.exists(path_data_anaconv):
    os.makedirs(path_data_anaconv)
```

Comment: Please show the code where you're trying to move a file

Comment: The movement of the files I plan to do it by hand from the directories that I have created. Other directories created in the same way do not present the same problem. As a matter of fact, the schematic of the folders is the following: Data (always the same) > Data + Charts. Charts do not give problems. Data is divided in Original and Conversion, and only Conversion gives problems, even empty. So the data inside is not problematic either.
Sorry for the difficult explanation.